# Unit/Integration tests with inmemory database don't work with IQueryables

Tags: entity-framework-core, ienumerable, iqueryable, in-memory-database

I'm trying to run some unit tests with inmemory database. I'm creating a new entity and then I'm checking if it exists or not. If I query as an `Task<IEnumerable<Entity>>` or a `Task<Entity>` with `FindAsync(id)`,I get the model, but if I check with `IQueryable<Entity>` I'm getting null. Is there a restriction with InMemory Db with IQueryables? Because I feel that it only fetches it because of `FindAsync()`;

Below is the code:

`var model = await _context.User.FindAsync(id);` returns model

```
var model = await GetUserModel(id);
Task<User> GetUserModel(int id)=>
await _context.User.FindAsync(id);
```

returns model

```
IQueryable<User> GetUser() =>
            _context.User
            .Include(u => u.Role)
            .AsQueryable();

var model = await GetUser().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

returns null

UnitTestSetup

```
protected static UserDbContext GetContext()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDb")
            .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
            .Options;
            return new UserDbContext(options);
        }
```

UnitTest

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task GetUsers_ShouldReturnUsers()
        {
            //Arrange
            var userService = new UserService(GetContext());
            await userService.CreateUser(Helpers.CreateUser());
            //Act
            var viewModel = await userService.GetUsers();
            //Assert
            viewModel.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        }
```

Edit:
After many tests it seems that my instinct is correct. If I use `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` it doesn't find the in memory created entity but if I use `FindAsync()` it does. If I compare a value of the created model with the model that `FindAsync()` fetches it returns true, so I know that my `IQueryable` method should be working.